# How can stop LaTeX from putting line breaks in math?

Tags: latex, line-breaks

I have several instances where LaTeX puts line breaks in math sections, which are all encased in $s. I have long documents, and going through each instance of this and fixing it manually is a pain. Is there any way to make LaTeX start the math sections on a new line whenever they would get spliced?

This is what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: There is a stackexchange site dedicated to TeX. You should ask there instead.

Comment: Try asking in http://tex.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea - you may end up with under- and overful lines.